# d'Alembert functional equation: $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)f(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

The d'Alembert functioal equation is:
$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)f(y)$$
This equation plays a central role in determining the sum of two vectors in
Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries.

Is there a good characterization of the solutions of this equation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are good resources about this equation, that have studied the solutions of
$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)f(y)\tag0\label0$$
or its generalizations. For example, [Functional Equations in
Several Variables](https://books.google.com/books/about/Functional_Equations_in_Several_Variable.html?id=8EWnEh18rVgC) by J. Aczel and J. Dhombers, or [Introduction to
Functional Equations](https://books.google.com/books?id=f2rRBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=kannappan%20sahoo%20functional&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi08uKytdPJAhUI_iwKHd8HB2MQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=kannappan%20sahoo%20functional&f=false) by P. Kannappan and P. Sahoo, and of course many
other books and papers which can be found on the internet. Here, I try to
solve the equation for two more common cases.

> - Every continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfying \eqref{0} is
>   of the form $f(x)=0$, $f(x)=\cos(\alpha x)$ or $f(x)=\cosh(\alpha x)$.

Letting $x=y=0$ in \eqref{0} we find out that $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$. If
$f(0)=0$, then letting $y=0$ in \eqref{0}, we infere that $f$ is the constant zero function. So let's suppose $f(0)=1$. Letting $x=0$ in \eqref{0}, we find
out that $f$ is an even function. Also, since $f$ is continuous, there is a positive $t$ such that for every $-t\leq y\leq t$ we have $f(y)>0$. Now, $f$ is locally integrable because it's continuous. Thus we have:
$$\int_{-t}^tf(x+y)\,dy+\int_{-t}^tf(x-y)\,dy=2f(x)\int_{-t}^tf(y)\,dy$$
$$\therefore\quad2\int_{x-t}^{x+t}f(y)\,dy=2f(x)\int_{-t}^tf(y)\,dy\tag1\label1$$
So by the fundumental theorem of calculus, the left hand side of \eqref{1} is a
differentiable function of $x$, because $f$ is continuous. Hence the right
hand side is differentiable too and we have:
$$f(x+t)-f(x-t)=f^\prime(x)\int_{-t}^tf(y)\,dy\tag2\label2$$
$$\therefore\quad f(t)-f(-t)=f^\prime(0)\int_{-t}^tf(y)\,dy$$
But since $f$ is even and $\int_{-t}^tf(y)\,dy>0$, we have $f^\prime(0)=0$.
Again, since $f$ is differentiable, so the left hand side of \eqref{2} is a
differentiable function of $x$ and thus the right hand side is so, which
yields that $f$ is two times differentiable (continuing this way, we can
prove that $f$ has derivatives of any order). Now, differentiating \eqref{0}
twice, with respect to $y$ we get:
$$f^{\prime\prime}(x+y)+f^{\prime\prime}(x-y)=2f(x)f^{\prime\prime}(y)$$
$$\therefore\quad f^{\prime\prime}(x)=f^{\prime\prime}(0)f(x)\tag3\label3$$
It's a well-known result of elementry differential equations that if $f$
satisfies \eqref{3} and $f(0)=1$ and $f^\prime(0)=0$, then
$f(x)=\cosh\left(\sqrt{f^{\prime\prime}(0)}x\right)$ when $f^{\prime\prime}(0)\geq0$ and
$f(x)=\cos\left(\sqrt{-f^{\prime\prime}(0)}x\right)$ when $f^{\prime\prime}(0)\leq0$.

> - A function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ is a solution of \eqref{0} iff it's of
>   the form $f(x)=\frac{E(x)+E(-x)}2$ for some $E:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$
>   satisfying $E(x+y)=E(x)E(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Assume that $E:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ satisfies $E(x+y)=E(x)E(y)$. we have:
$$\frac{E(x+y)+E(-x-y)}2+\frac{E(x-y)+E(-x+y)}2\\
=\frac{E(x)E(y)+E(-x)E(-y)+E(x)E(-y)+E(-x)E(y)}2\\
=2\cdot\frac{E(x)+E(-x)}2\cdot\frac{E(y)+E(-y)}2$$
So $\frac{E(x)+E(-x)}2$ satisfies \eqref{0}. Conversly, suppose that $f$
satisfies \eqref{0}. If $f$ is the constant zero function, then we let $E$ be
the constant zero function and we would have $f(x)=\frac{E(x)+E(-x)}2$ and
$E(x+y)=E(x)E(y)$. Otherwise, $f(0)$ must be equal to $1$. Now, letting $y=x$
in \eqref{0} we get:
$$f(2x)=2f(x)^2-1$$
Replacing $x$ by $x+y$ and $y$ by $x-y$ in \eqref{0} we have:
$$f(2x)+f(2y)=2f(x+y)f(x-y)$$
$$\therefore\quad f(x+y)f(x-y)=f(x)^2+f(y)^2-1$$
Thus we conclude that:
$$\big(f(x+y)-f(x)f(y)\big)^2\\
=f(x+y)^2-2f(x)f(y)f(x+y)+f(x)^2f(y)^2\\
=f(x+y)^2-\big(f(x+y)+f(x-y)\big)f(x+y)+f(x)^2f(y)^2$$
$$\therefore\quad\big(f(x+y)-f(x)f(y)\big)^2=\left(f(x)^2-1\right)
\left(f(y)^2-1\right)\tag4\label4$$
Now, if for every $x$ we have $f(x)=-1$ or $f(x)=1$, then by \eqref{4} we have
$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$. Since in this case $f(x)f(-x)=1$, if we let $E(x):=f(x)$
then $f(x)=\frac{E(x)+E(-x)}2$ and $E(x+y)=E(x)E(y)$. So let's suppose that
for some $x_0$ we have $f(x_0)\neq-1$ and $f(x_0)\neq1$. We define
$\alpha=f(x_0)$, $\beta^2:=\alpha^2-1$ and $E(x):=\frac1\beta\big(f(x+x_0)+
(\beta-\alpha)f(x)\big)$. By \eqref{4} we have:
$$\big(E(x)-f(x)\big)^2=\frac1{\beta^2}\big(f(x+x_0)-f(x_0)f(x)\big)^2=f(x)^2-1$$
$$\therefore\quad E(x)^2-2f(x)E(x)+1=0$$
$$\therefore\quad f(x)=\frac{E(x)+E(x)^{-1}}2$$
Next we consider:
$$E(x)E(y)=\frac1{\beta^2}\big(f(x+x_0)+(\beta-\alpha)f(x)\big)
\big(f(y+x_0)+(\beta-\alpha)f(y)\big)\\
=\frac1{\beta^2}\Big(f(x+x_0)f(y+x_0)+(\beta-\alpha)\big(f(x)f(y+x_0)+f(y)f(x+x_0)\big)+
(\beta-\alpha)^2f(x)f(y)\Big)\tag5\label5$$
We also note that by \eqref{0}:
$$2f(x+x_0)f(y+y_0)=f(x+y+2x_0)+f(x-y)\\
=\big(2f(x_0)f(x+y+x_0)-f(x+y)\big)+\big(2f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)\big)\\
=2\big(\alpha f(x+y+x_0)+f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)\big)\tag6\label6$$
And again by \eqref{0}:
$$2\big(f(x)f(y+x_0)+f(y)f(x+x_0)\big)\\
=2f(x+y+x_0)+f(x_0+x-y)+f(x_0-x+y)\\
=2f(x+y+x_0)+2f(x_0)f(x-y)\\
=2\Big(f(x+y+x_0)+\alpha\big(f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)\big)\Big)\tag7\label7$$
Combining \eqref{5}, \eqref{6} and \eqref{7} we get:
$$E(x)E(y)\\
=\frac1{\beta^2}\Big(\left((\beta-\alpha)^2+2\alpha(\beta-\alpha)+1\right)
f(x)f(y)+\beta f(x+y+x_0)-\big(1+\alpha(\beta-\alpha)\big)f(x+y)\Big)\\
=\frac1{\beta^2}\Big(\left(\beta^2-\alpha^2+1\right)f(x)f(y)+\beta
f(x+y+x_0)-\left(\alpha\beta+1-\alpha^2\right)f(x+y)\Big)\\
=\frac1{\beta^2}\big(\beta f(x+y+x_0)+\beta(\beta-\alpha)f(x+y)\big)$$
$$\therefore\quad E(x)E(y)=E(x+y)$$
Since $E(x)E(-x)=1$ we have $f(x)=\frac{E(x)+E(-x)}2$.