# A function satisfying $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)f(y)$ and $f(x_0)=-1$ is periodic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, periodic-functions, even-and-odd-functions

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying that $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)f(y)$ forall $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=-1$. Prove that $f$ is a periodic function.

Here is what I did.

First, letting $x=y=0$, I have $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$. If $f(0)=0$ then $f\equiv 0$, contradiction. Hence $f(0)=1$. Letting $y=0$, I have $f$ is an even function.

After that, letting $y=x_0$ implies that
$f(x+x_0)+f(x)=-\big(f(x)+f(x-x_0)\big)$. It means that, if $g(x)=f(x)+f(x-x_0)$ then $g(x+2x_0)=g(x)$ and thus $g$ is a period function.

I have tried to calculate some special values. I have proved that $f(2^nx_0)=1,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

I'm stuck here. Can somebody help me?

Comment: It's pretty easy to show that $f(n\cdot x_0)=(-1)^n$ for all integers $n\ge 0$ with induction

Comment: yeah! I have proved that.

Comment: This is called *d'Alembert's functional equation*. Take a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1570977/229831) for more information on its solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $f$ isn't the zero function. Set $y=0$ then $2f(x)=2f(x)f(0)$, whence $f(0)=1$.

Put $x=y=x_0/2$, then
$$0=f(x_0)+f(0)=2f(x_0/2)^2,$$
whence $f(x_0/2)=0$. Now, for any $z\in\mathbb{R}$, put $x=z+x_0/2$ and $y=x_0/2$, then
$$f(z)+f(z-x_0)=2f(z-x_0)f(x_0/2)=0,$$
so $f(z-x_0)=-f(z)$. Hence, $f(z-2x_0)=f(z)$. We are done.