# Find $f(7)$ given $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)+f(x-y)$ and $f(1)=3$

Tags: functional-equations

> Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(1)=3$ and $f$ satisfies the functional equation
> $$f(x)f(y) = f(x+y) + f(x-y)$$
> Find the value of $f(7)$.

**Attempt:**

If $x=1$ and $y=0$, we find

$$f(1) f(0) = 2f(1) \implies f(0) = 2$$

If we fix $y=1$, we get the recurrence relation

$$\begin{cases} f(0) = 2 \\ f(1) = 3 \\ f(x + 1) - 3f(x) + f(x - 1) = 0 & \text{for } x\ge1 \end{cases}$$

From here I can solve for $f(x)$ or sequentially compute $f(2),f(3),f(4),\ldots$ to arrive at $f(7) = 843$.

**Question:**

> Is there a more elegant way of finding $f(7)$ directly from the functional equation?

Comment: well you can solve the linear induction relation $u_n=f(n)$ satisfying $u_{n+2}-3u_{n+1}+u_n=0\iff u_n=(1+\varphi)^n+(1-\frac 1{\varphi})^n$ and calculate $u_7$ but not sure if this really is easier considering that $f(7)$ is quite accessible quickly.

Comment: I believe this is $f(n)=L_{2n}$ where $L$ is the Lucas numbers, defined by $L_0=2$, $L_1=1$, and $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$ (the same recurrence as the Fibonacci numbers). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) lists some identities, one of which implies $L_{2n}=F_{2n-1}+F_{2n+1}$.

Comment: (only for integer inputs)

Comment: For complete resolution note that if you set $f(x)=2g(x)$ then $g$ is solution of **d'Alembert functional equation** of the form $\cos(\alpha x)$ or $\cosh(\alpha x)$ depending on initial conditions. See for instance here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1570977/399263

Comment: @zwim Thanks for the reference. I had a feeling this equation was named.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, is not too fancy, but you could do

$f(7)=f(4+3)=f(4)f(3)-f(1),$

and using the fact that
$f(4)=f(3)f(1)-f(2),$

you could compute $f(7)$ by knowing only $f(1),\;f(2),$ and $f(3)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Evaluate $\pmb{f(0)}$**

$f(1)=3$ and
$$
f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)+f(x-y)\tag1
$$
Setting $x=1$ and $y=0$, $(1)$ gives $f(0)=2$.

---

**Determine and Solve a Recursion**

Setting $y=1$, $(1)$ gives
$$
3f(x)=f(x+1)+f(x-1)\tag2
$$
Solving the [second order linear recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients#Order_2) in $(2)$ and using $f(0)=2$ and $f(1)=3$ gives, for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}2\right)^{\large\!x}+\left(\frac{3-\sqrt5}2\right)^{\large\!x}\tag{3a}\\
&=\phi^{2x}+\phi^{-2x}\tag{3b}\\[6pt]
&=L_{2x}\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
where $L_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ [Lucas Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) (as Akiva Weinberger [mentioned in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536280/find-f7-given-fxfy-fxyfx-y-and-f1-3/4536641#comment9535820_4536280)).

---

**Check the Functional Equation $\pmb{(1)}$**

If $(1)$ has a solution, then it is given by $(3)$. However, to show that $(1)$ has a solution, we need to verify that $(3)$ satisfies $(1)$.
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)f(y)
&=\left(\phi^{2x}+\phi^{-2x}\right)\left(\phi^{2y}+\phi^{-2y}\right)\tag{4a}\\[4pt]
&=\phi^{2(x+y)}+\phi^{-2(x+y)}+\phi^{2(x-y)}+\phi^{-2(x-y)}\tag{4b}\\[6pt]
&=f(x+y)+f(x-y)\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
So, $(1)$ is satisfied.

---

**Apply to the Question**

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
f(7)
&=L_{14}\tag{5a}\\[4pt]
&=843\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You probably want to double-check that the $f(x)$ you derive satisfies the functional equation (it does)

Comment: Since both $r_1=\frac{3+\sqrt5}2$ and $r_1=\frac{3-\sqrt5}2$ satisfy $r^2-3r+1=0$, $f(x)=r_1^x+r_2^x$ satisfies $(2)$, at least for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I meant checking (1). Just because (1) implies (2) doesn't mean (2) implies (1).