# A functional equation with trigonometric solution

Tags: functional-equations

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)f(y)$$
for all real $x$ and $y$. Find all possible functions $f(x)$.

The optimal solutions are
$f(x)=0$, $f(x)=1$, $f(x)=\cos x$, but I can't fully solve the question.

Some things that I have proved:

1. $f(x)$ is even
2. $f(x)$ is periodic

- Let $T>0$ be the least number such that $f(x+T)=f(x)$, then we have $f(T)=1$, $f(T/2)=-1$, $f(T/4)=0$

3. There exists some $r$ such that $f(r)=0$

I may want to assume $z(x)=f(x)+ig(x)$ where $z:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Then we may have $z(x+y)=z(x)z(y)$.

Comment: What makes a solution "optimal"? Isn't $f(x)=\cos(ax)$ a solution for all real $a$?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1570977/42969

Comment: Point 3 $(\exists r\quad f(r)=0)$ is redundant: you wrote $f(T/4)=0$ just before.